# ExtJS align radiogroup in form

Tags: extjs

I am looking for way to setup FormPanel that labels will be aligned left on left side (this is default) and field aligned rigth on right side - they are aligned left...

how long I am dealing with DisplayField, TextField, or NumberField adding

```
ctCls:  'x-form-element-currency',
```

where

```
.x-form-element-currency {
   text-align: right;
}
```

do the work and is nicely aligned to right

My problem start when I try to do this same with radiogroup element (I want to have Yes-No radio select)

ctCls: what adding class to the correct (in my opinion) container abowe radiogroup does not make aligment...

What I do wrong ?

Comment: I started trying to figure out how to help you. Then I realized: I don't understand your question at all. Maybe a picture of what you are trying to accomplish will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about :

```
...
anchor: 'right',
...
```